# Как уничтожить элемент UserСontrol?

Tags: c#, .net

Метода `Close` нету, `Finalize` - защищенный, посылка `WM_CLOSE` тоже ничего не дает.

Comment: Прежде всего уточните, что Вы понимаете под "уничтожить"? Скрыть его с формы `(control.Visible = false)`? Убрать его с формы? Освободить занимаемые им ресурсы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо убрать его с формы:

```
Controls.Remove(userControl);
```

А чтобы совсем убить, надо обнулить все ссылки на него и вызвать гарбадж коллектор, но обычно это лишнее.

```
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Алсо, если контрол имплементирует интерфейс `IDisposable`, нужно после удаления из коллекции контролов вызвать метод `Dispose`.

Замечание: вызывать явно сборку мусора не очень рекомендуется. Во-первых, дотнету самому виднее, а во-вторых, вызов `GC.Collect()` не гарантирует освобождение памяти из-под тех объектов, на которых нет ссылок.

Comment: @andreycha, Метод `Dispose` явно высвобождает не управляемые ресурсы, управляемые так же помечаются для удаления сборщику мусора.

Также `GC.Collect()` [гарантирует][1] высвобождение памяти у тех объектов у которых нет ссылок в управляемом коде. 

Также если Вы почитаете [здесь][2], то Dispose не гарантирует высвобождение управляемой памяти занятой объектом - он готовит его для возможности повторного использования. 

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xe0c2357
[2]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx

Comment: 1) Это смотря как он реализован. Может освобождать, а может и нет.
2) В общем случае не гарантирует. Поскольку если у объекта определен метод `Finalize()`, то после первого коллекта объект будет перемещен в следующее поколение и поставлен в очередь финализации. И только после того, как отработает финализатор и дойдет дело до сборки этого поколение, память будет освобождена. Вот из-за начилия таких тонкостей и не рекомендуют командовать коллектором явно.
3) Да, я знаю. Но если вы хотите расстаться с объектом, то этот метод крайне желательно вызывать (а вопрос был именно об этом).

Answer (score 0):

[`UserControl.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.dispose.aspx)

Comment: Не вводите в заблуждение, а также сами почитайте документацию. Вызов `Dispose()` не уничтожает объект и не освобождает занимаемую им память. Метод `Dispose()` предназначен для освобождения ресурсов, которые использует данный класс.

Comment: А разве речь идёт об освобождении памяти?